# What does XPM use for Default Content Types?

Tags: experience-manager

I want to confirm behavior I'm seeing in XPM.

1. Edit XPM page with three Promos.
2. Remove Component Presentation `Promo 1` (XPM saves changes)
3. `Create and Insert New Content`

It seems XPM uses the last major version of the page as I get a copy of the CP (`Promo 1`) I just removed.

**Questions**:

1. For default content types, how does XPM choose which CP to use (first, last, which page version, etc.)?
2. And to be sure, is XPM using the CPs saved in the CMS to generate these default options (rather than reading the SiteEdit markup on the page)?

**Update:** forgot to mention the final list of Default ("already used on the Page") and custom "Predefined" Content Types is also based on Inline Settings for a given Page Template and Publication.